# codeGoogleCom exported Wiki, how to merge it?

Tags: git, github

[`code.google.com` is exporting](https://code.google.com/p/support-tools/wiki/GitHubExporterFAQ#Where_did_my_Google_Code_wikis_go?)   all projects to Github... And when export, produce a separated branch named `wiki` for the Wiki of the project...

My project has only Wiki... Now, at Github,

```
https://github.com/MyUser/MyProject
```

the MyProject (exported from code.google) is "empty" (no source code, etc.), have only a `README.md`. So, **how to merge the *wiki* branch to the *master*?**

See also [How to do a GitHub "merge branch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29184227/287948)

---

NOTE

With the help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4568323/287948) we can see how to clone the `wiki` branch,

```
   git clone -b wiki stdGithubMyProjectURL
   cd MyProject
   ls
```

(where stdGithubMyProjectURL is the standard Github copy-URL of MyProject)

(the `ls` command in this context show **only** the *branch* `wiki` files, not show any *master* file)

so, a variant of this question is **how to merge `wiki` to `master` from terminal?**

---

I [see finishGoogleCodeGitHubWikiMigration](https://github.com/morgant/finishGoogleCodeGitHubWikiMigration) ... but it is so complex and "obscure"... not try to use.

Comment: As the developer of [finishGoogleCodeGitHubWikiMigration](https://github.com/morgant/finishGoogleCodeGitHubWikiMigration), I just wanted to provide a little explanation. A rebase is one solution, but since no wiki history is preserved in the export from Google Code, and to preserve possible existing wiki pages, I decided to go with a commit instead. It also fixes wiki page links so they are functional (the ones from the wiki branch only work if you're browsing that branch, not if rebased into the wiki). It was originally written for my own projects, hence `bash`, though it's clean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My project has only Wiki... Now, at Github,

You could simply push your local wiki branch as the master of your GitHub repo

```
git push --force -u origin wiki:master
```

Don't forget though that each GitHub repo has a second "wiki" repo, as I mentioned in "[Effortless export from GitHub wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18760262/6309)" (Just add "`.wiki`" to any repository name in the GitHub URL).
That means you could also push to the wiki part of your (empty) GitHub repo.

---

Independently of the "wiki" nature of the local repo, if you simply want to get your branch "on top" of the existing master GitHub repo, all you need to do is:

```
cd /path/to/your/local/repo
git remote set-url origin https://<yourName>@github.com/<yourname>/<yourrepo>
git fetch
git rebase origin master
git push -u origin master
```

---

### complete procedure for dummies

For a repo which already has a wiki branch (like [`ppKrauss/smallest-template-system`](https://github.com/ppKrauss/smallest-template-system/tree/wiki) has), you can replay it on top of master and then push to master:

```
git clone https://github.com/ppKrauss/smallest-template-system.git
cd smallest-template-system
git checkout -b wiki origin/wiki
#ls
git rebase master
#ls 
git checkout master
git reset --hard wiki
git push
```

Explain: the first checkout switch to the `wiki` branch and an `ls` will show only the branch files.  The `rebase` git command do the "merge of files" here, the second `ls` will show the README file of the *master* branch.

Comment: Near solution (!), I agree and using... But it destroy the master (lost the original README file of the master)... This command is like to rename master to wiki, not do a real merge.

Comment: about the use of .wiki directive,  it's ok, if the command moves `wiki` *branch* to the `.wiki` *folder* at *master*, ok.

Comment: @PeterKrauss for the first one, I figured it was ok, since your repo has only the README.md (meaning it was practically empty)

Comment: @PeterKrauss as for the wiki, it is an independent repo, not the same repo as the GitHub one.

Comment: Sorry, the project have "no code" (is empty of relevant things) but have readme content... Perhaps the problem here is a [`rebase`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14681796/287948) problem, but I not understand how to do (need in a simple way)

Comment: @PeterKrauss Ok, I have edited the answer with the rebase step.

Comment: Thanks a lot (!), well I will test later... About your `cd /path/to/your/local/repo` it is [my `cd MyProject`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29184375/287948) or you clone first the *master* (default clone)? What the starting point to a safe use of your commands?

Comment: @PeterKrauss I assumed that you have your google code repo cloned locally: that was my starting point.

Comment: See the question, I say `git clone -b wiki stdGithubMyProjectURL`, but you say? `git clone  stdGithubMyProjectURL`

Comment: Well, testing (!)  Google exported https://github.com/ppKrauss/smallest-template-system  and https://github.com/ppKrauss/smallest-template-system/branches

Comment: @PeterKrauss sorry, I forgot "remote": `git remote set-url`

Comment: ... hum not works, master stay with only readme... `git remote set-url origin https://ppKrauss@github.com/ppKrauss/smallest-template-system
git fetch
git rebase origin master
git push -u origin master
`

Comment: need to start with the branch clone??  `git clone -b wiki stdGithubMyProjectURL`

Comment: @PeterKrauss both repos you mentioned have already a wiki branch. I have edited the answer to replay it on top of master, and reset master to it.

Comment: Ok, [it works!!](https://github.com/ppKrauss/smallest-template-system) I edited to add little syntax correction... Now can DELETE all this comments... Only if you preffer to stay they here.

Comment: @PeterKrauss the comments are instructive to understand how we got there together.