# How can I save github markdown file as a HTML or PDF?

Tags: html, pdf, markdown

I have to send my document to HTML or PDF format but there is no save as PDF/HTML button on github page. How can I do that? Is there an online tool or something?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting multiple Markdown files with links to PDF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14899283/converting-multiple-markdown-files-with-links-to-pdf)

Comment: This answer describes it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8050241/2444130

Comment: It just does not work for me, just produce a garbage for me

Comment: @akhikhl: thx, Grip (Github Readme Instant Preview) does an awesome job for me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [GitPrint](https://github.com/adamburmister/gitprint.com) - a conversor from Github Markdown to PDF.

Comment: Thx, It works. But I did the job with Grip a year ago. But I accept this answer because this is the only one.

Comment: gitprint does not support images

Comment: seems  not to be working any more.